# SQL: Result for Points Outside Polygons

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, pgadmin

I have an SQL statement which creates a point based on an address search, and returns a value based on where the point lies. If it is within a part of a polygon with a certain attribute value, it returns a corresponding result (see CASE statement below).

```
SELECT
CASE
        WHEN p.column1 IS NOT NULL AND p.column2 = 'Yes' THEN 'Response_A'
        WHEN p.column1 IS NOT NULL AND p.column2 = 'No' THEN 'Response_B'
        WHEN p.column1 IS NOT NULL AND p.column2 IS NULL THEN 'Response_C'
        ELSE 'Outside Polygon'
    END AS Status,
    p.column1,
    p.column2,
    p.geometry
FROM
    my.table AS p
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE), 4326),
    ST_Transform(p.geometry, 4326))
```

However, my issue lies where points do not fall within the polygons. If I run the above (with a Longitude and Latitude that I know are within a polygon) I return a result as expected, with the expected response. But if I plug in values that are *outwith* any polygons, the table is blank, it returns nothing. I though that the ELSE statement would have accounted for this, but it doesn't seem to work.
I would appreciate any advice as I am completely stumped.

The result I am looking for is that if the long/lat are not in a polygon, then it should return 'outside polygon'.

I have tried the below methods to fix:

- Replace ST_Intersects with ST_Within; produces the same issue
- Add another CASE statement;

```
WHEN NOT ST_Within(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE}), 4326), p.geometry) THEN 'Outside Polygon'
```

but that doesn't seem to have an effect,

- I also tried adding in a Left Join to the table itself but I couldn't get that to work.

******EDIT******

Thanks for the kind response :) This is the query that ended up working for me:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM my.table AS p
            WHERE
                ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326), ST_Transform(p.geometry, 4326))
                AND p.column1 IS NOT NULL
                AND p.column2 = 'Yes'
        ) THEN 'Response A'
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM my.table AS p
            WHERE
                ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326), ST_Transform(p.geometry, 4326))
                AND p.column1 IS NOT NULL
                AND p.column2 = 'No'
        ) THEN 'Response B'
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM my.table AS p
            WHERE
                ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326), ST_Transform(p.geometry, 4326))
                AND p.column1 IS NOT NULL
                AND p.column2 IS NULL
        ) THEN 'Response C'
        WHEN NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM my.table AS p
            WHERE
                ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326), ST_Transform(p.geometry, 4326))
        ) THEN 'Outside Polygon'
        ELSE 'Error'
    END AS Status,
    (
        SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326) AS point
    ) AS CreatedPoint;
```

Comment: please add create table with some data as text to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WHERE clause is preventing any points outside the polygon.
ST_Intersects Returns true if two geometries intersect.
ST_Within Returns TRUE if geometry A is within geometry B.
You will need to adjust or remove your WHERE clause to include points outside the polygon.

Comment: Thanky you for reaching out! I if I understand you correctly, this means if I take out the INTERSECTS clause, it would work?

Comment: When developing a SQL statement I usually try without a WHERE clause first. Instead I specify SELECT Top 10 * FROM my.table....   I then review the results and select which columns I want.  SELECT Top 10  'Example Status' as Status, Column1, Column2, geometry FROM my.table.  Identifying which rows to exclude via the WHERE clause is one of the last steps. When I am done I remove the Top 10 part.

Comment: @I_suck_at_sql if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and gives you some reputation.

Comment: If you put the intersection into the case statements it would work

Comment: @IanTurton that is my line of enquiry today! thanks.